# How can I fix UI Control Map controls from losing their mappings?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests

I am creating a Coded UI Test on my machine (Windows 8.1) by creating all the mappings and manually writing the tests. (I do not use Action Recordings) When they run at night on my Nightly machine (Server 2012R2) the action to select my Group Lookup window actually selects my Customer Code lookup window during the test run.

Remapping the controls on my machine does not fix this, and it is not possible to remap them on the Server2012R2 machine as it is only meant to run the tests not to run Visual Studio.

The available search properties on the control are not helpful enough to differentiate the controls. Instead I tried modifying the Friendly Name property on the control and used the following code:

```
public void ClickControl(WinControl mycontrol, string resultId)
{
    UITestControlCollection controls = mycontrol.FindMatchingControls();
    foreach (UITestControl allControls in controls)
    {
        if (allControls.FriendlyName == resultId)
        {
            Mouse.Click(allControls);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run the code it seems to not use the modified value of the Friendly Name when the program is running.

Is there a way to ensure I am selecting the correct control before I send the Mouse.Click event?

Comment: are you sure the `Customer Code lookup window` has the correct `FriendlyName`?

Comment: The customer code lookup's friendly name was "..." so was the Group Code lookup's friendly name. I changed them to "CustCodeLookup" and "GroupCodeLookup" respectively. When i ran the above function on the Group Code lookup, it was still passing in "..." when i called allControls.FriendlyName.

Comment: Try something like `someDebugOutputStream.Writeline("Friendlyname '{0}'", allControls.FriendlyName);` just before the `if...`. Note the `'` characters in the output, so leading/training spaces etc are revealed.

Comment: I already know what the friendlyname is for the control that I am accessing, but the friendlyname currently is not helpful as it is the same as 12 other controls. Using the FriendlyName is only helpful if I can successfully change it, which I can't seem to manage.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around by creating the following method. It's not as clean as I would like and I have to use the UIMap tool to find the ControlName, but the code is making my tests pass when I call it.

```
public static UITestControl FindControl(WinControl myControl, string controlName)
        {
            try
            {
                UITestControlCollection controls = myControl.FindMatchingControls();
                foreach (UITestControl currentControl in controls)
                {
                    if (currentControl.ControlType == ControlType.Button)
                    {
                        WinButton mycont = (WinButton)currentControl;
                        if (mycont.ControlName == controlName)
                        {
                            return mycont;
                        }
                    }
                    if (currentControl.ControlType == ControlType.Edit)
                    {
                        WinEdit mycont = (WinEdit)currentControl;
                        if (mycont.ControlName == controlName)
                        {
                            return mycont;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return myControl;
            }
            catch
            {
                return myControl;
            }
        }
```